# Create an SMS shortcut on homescreen?

Tags: applications, ios, sms, iphone

Is there an application the creates a homescreen shortcut that sends a particular message to a specific number when pressed ?

---

So basically something that allows :

- Add number
- Add text message
- Create homescreen shortcut

Now every time I click that shortcut, it sends the sms to that number directly.

---

Comment: This would be a great feature. Chances are one would have to jailbreak their phone to get this to a truly one-click process (just tapping to open the app).

Comment: @bassplayer7 Something like iCustom would work fine if there is an extra option to add text !!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [LaunchCenter Pro](http://contrast.co/launch-center-pro/):

> It’s like speed dial for anything you do with your iPhone or iPod Touch. Create one-tap shortcuts straight to the feature you need
>   inside of your apps.
>
> Message a loved one, search Yelp for the nearest coffee shop, jump
>   straight to the camera in Instagram, all with just a flick of your
>   thumb. Create shortcuts for email, Safari, phone or FaceTime calls,
>   Google searches, and more. If you do it on your phone constantly,
>   Launch Center Pro will make it easier and faster.
>
> Sample shortcuts:
>
> Call a loved one Message a friend Email your boss Fire up Instagram’s
>   camera instantly Search Yelp for nearby coffee shops Jump right to
>   your favorite website Create a new item in OmniFocus Search Twitter
>   using Tweetbot Use the iPhone as a flashlight And so much more...

I haven't tried it, personally but the description above seems to indicate it will work. You might also follow the recent news that some of the features of LaunchCenter pro are [being disabled at Apple's request by the developer](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/10/15/apple-undocumented-apis/).

Comment: Hmm I would like someone to confirm if the app does what I need. Don't really wanna pay $5 for it just to see if it does.

Answer (score 1):

### [iCustom](http://icustom.tooliphone.net)

iCustom allows you to create app icons to send SMS messages (or perform other actions such as calling people, etc).

You can choose a service, phone number and icon, then save it to your home screen. Tapping on the icon initiates the action that you set it up to do.

This is a free, web-based service that uses Safari's Save to Home Screen feature to save the icon *directly* to the home screen.

Comment: This is great but it doesn't specify what text to be typed automatically. It allows to open the sms app for that specific number, but I have to type the content.